# What compliance and legal clearances are required to use Google MAP API with Iphone Apps?

Tags: api, google-maps

We are using 2 following google services, we need to talk to google folks if we need to do some additional stuff to fulfill the conditions:

1. Reverse Geocoding APIs: For getting city and state from the iphone's geocodes (latitudes and longitudes)
2. Doing a Local Business Search: based on city and state

Also is it mandatory to embade Google maps with iphone apps while using these Google Maps APS?:

Answer (score 0):

I thought you only needed to provide your own map licensing if you were providing turn by turn instructions. Indeed in iPhone 3.0 the Google Map is a fully fledged UI component for developer usage.